# Action based on visiblity and duration of element in viewport

Tags: javascript

I am using IntersectionObserver to know whether a particular element is visible to the user or not. If it is visible then I am fetching some data from the server-side. Now I would like to know whether there is any API/approach to know how long an element is visible to the user.

The use case that I am trying to solve is this - If an element is visible in the viewport for 5secs then fetch some data from the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to `setTimeout` for 5 sec when it started to be visible, then check if it's still visible.

Comment: @Kosh You would also need to clear the timeout if it became hidden, otherwise it would allow it to be visible, then hidden for 3 seconds, then visible again when the second check happens, and still trigger the API.

Comment: @DBS, absolutely agree.

Answer (score 1):

```
const scrollArea = document.querySelector('.scroll-area');

let executeApiCall = null;

const observer = new IntersectionObserver( event => {
  console.log(`intersect`, event);

  if ( event[0].intersectionRatio === 0 ) {
    console.log('element not in viewport');
    clearTimeout(executeApiCall);
  } else {
    console.log('element is in viewport');
    if(!executeApiCall) {
      executeApiCall = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('api call');
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
}, {
  root: scrollArea
});
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/intersection-observer-hynpuj

Answer (score 0):

If return `true`
after `setTimeout` execute your next code...

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("app");

function isInViewportFunc(el){
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.bottom < 0 || rect.right < 0 || rect.left > window.innerWidth || rect.top < window.innerHeight;
}

console.log(
isInViewportFunc(elem)

)
```

```html
<br/>
<br/><br/>
<br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="app">Text</div>
```